# Node.js - does not detect the same data

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, string, equals

I'm comparing two strings I get from the SQL database and the html form but the equals don't work.

```
    if (database.recordset[0].name=== myString) {
          console.log("work");
    }else{
          console.log("dont work");
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
dont work
```

**Read data with console**

```
console.log(database.recordset[0].name);
console.log(myString);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
asdasd
asdasd
```

But if not working...

**EDIT**

I used this:

```
 console.log(typeof database.recordset[0].name);
 console.log(typeof myString);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  string
  string
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing MySQL and other variables the main difference between "==" and "===" operator is that formerly compares variable by making type correction e.g. if you compare a number with a string with numeric literal, == allows that, but === doesn't allow that, because it not only checks the value but also type of two variable, if two variables are not of the same type "===" return false, while "==" return true.

```
<script> 
// In R.H.S. string "3" is converted into 
// number 3, hence returns true. 
document.write(9 == "9");  

// used for next line 
document.write('<br>') 

// Here no type conversion takes place, 
// hence returns false 
document.write(9 === "9");
```

here is another example with strings

```js
    // Here L.H.S. is a string literal whereas 
    // R.H.S. is a string object, 
    // due to type conversion of string object into  
    // a string literal, it returns true. 
    document.write("GeeksforGeeks" == new String("GeeksforGeeks")); 
  
    // used for next line 
    document.write('<br>') 
  
    // No type conversion takes place 
    document.write("GeeksforGeeks" === new String("GeeksforGeeks"));
```

Comment: Ok try put database.recordset[0].name into a variable first before comparing as I think the IF statement is comparing a call to the database with a string